Are solar panels a good idea when my energy supply is already 'green'?
For many years I have been wondering about installing solar panels on our roof. It's E-W facing, so I've always thought that it wouldn't be very cost-effective. But panels are improving, so I have recently received two quotes for installing panels and a battery.
As I see it, there are only 2 reasons to install solar:

to use 'green' energy rather than fossil fuels (or nuclear)
to save money (in the long term)

Because of the orientation of our house, our payback time would be 12-13 years which is higher than the 10 years or less I understand is possible for a south-facing roof.
For the last few years we have been buying all our electricity (and gas) from a company which claims to buy all its power from truly green sources. So, in our case, it's debatable whether installing the panels would be sensible environmentally - I'm sure industrial-scale panels installed by our supplier would be more efficient, and if that supplier puts all profits into new solar panels and wind turbines any money we saved from our own bills would otherwise be used to enhance green power generation nationally.
And of course manufacturing and installing all the equipment isn't environmentally neutral either.
So I can't decide whether to go ahead or not - any thoughts?

Just to add: your energy company does not source all of its power from truly green sources, only 60% (via power purchasing agreements). The other 40% is from Renewable Energy Guarantees of Origin, which are a bit of a scam in the UK. There's not actually enough renewable energy generated to cover all the claims made by companies via REGOs. And their gas generation method uses a vast amount of land, better used for food production, so not necessarily "green". Better to control your own energy generation rather than believe the claims of a company.

Also consider the fact that you will be adding to the total solar capacity, and freeing up grid capacity to allow someone else to use the grid solar electricity currently "allocated" to you.

what's the marginal cost of orienting your solar panels properly? (it might depend on building regulations in your area but still)

It depends on many factors.
If your supplier provides green energy, you have one argument less in favour, but it still depends:

The main argument is always the economic one. Solar panels are usual economically convenient, but it adds risks. So overall for a town is convenient, but what if some very strong hail, or maybe some animals which break some cable and cause a fire to the solar panel? This is a sort of tragedy of the commons: if you have money, you save and make more money, else you have no money to safely invest. So if you do not have much money, I would not be the first mover, but I'll check others: the panels lasts and gives the planed energy?

Price security: with PV you do a huge initial investment, but then the marginal costs are low (just maintenance costs). With the electrical utility you never know (but on both directions)

Security of supply: less risk of black-out (batteries may not be huge, but you may get enough for your refrigerators).

Environmental: it may help to get more green energy overall. But that depends much on local conditions: is your utility delivering to all customers only green energy? It may help them to have more green (and cheap) production, and so expand the base.

Environmental 2: one of the complain of various renewable energy is about space they take. Your roof is already built, so no need for a new wind turbine or a PV farm in a green field.


Local utility (and city) may help (subsidies) roof PV. We consume more electricity, but so it causes problems on transmission and distribution lines. Decentralized production may reduce some peak load, and so more time to improve the lines (as you know, there is never money for that, until problem arise).
Grey energy (production, transport, end-of-life): usually irrelevant (transmission lines have a lot of metals, also some concrete). Each transformer and kilometer of line has loses.

As the context is the UK, we don't have local utilities or local subsidies - that's central government stuff.  But local authorities can still do a bit. I got my panels on what was effectively a bulk-buying scheme so ended up with slightly better stuff for slightly less money than going it alone. Regarding security of supply, that's an option - I have emergency sockets near my freezer (much easier=cheaper than a whole-house backup power system; everything else is either portable or I can run an extension lead)

... With dynamic pricing growing and supply/demand patterns, west-facing solar could be quite desirable.  Yes the total generation is less than south-facing, but it's at a useful time of day.  I'm not sure if you can currently benefit from this for exporting to the grid in the UK, but combined with a battery  (which may also be charged cheaply overnight helping balance the grid) it could still be useful on some tariffs

Re security of supply: not all PV installations (at least in Germany), even with a battery, are autonomous in the case of a power cut. Our inverter needs mains electricity; I think it is to do with getting the frequency right.

@PJTraill: the old one yes, and also for safety reasons. The new one may be used also without electricity (check local regulation, not all utilities relaxed the rule). But in such case, the electrical installation must be done for such support, e.g. own grounding. In case of power cut, all connection to to the line must be disconnected (line, neutral, earth). -- Some years ago it was not easy/possible (and expensive), but it is feasible and not much more expensive.
